# Flink job deployed on YARN fails with exit code 243

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I am trying to launch a Flink job on a YARN cluster like this

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 2 -yjm 1024 -ytm 2048 -c myclass flink-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Unfortunately the job is failing with a message that the JobManager could not be contacted. The same job does run successfully on a YARN cluster consisting of only one node (pseudo-cluster). flink-yarn-yaml points to the correct location of the Hadoop configuration. The YARN application logs of the job also contain no valuable information as of what could have gone wrong. The communication between the client and the worker nodes should happen without any problems, since other cluster-related technologies like Spark, Hive, MR work without problems.

Could you please hint what could have gone wrong here? I also tried to enable the zookeeper leader election in flink-conf.yaml and didn't help either.

```
13-09-2017 16:20:32 org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.createDescriptor main INFO  - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
13-09-2017 16:20:32 org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.createDescriptor main INFO  - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
13-09-2017 16:20:32 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deployInternal main INFO  - Using values:
13-09-2017 16:20:32 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deployInternal main INFO  -     TaskManager count = 2
13-09-2017 16:20:32 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deployInternal main INFO  -     JobManager memory = 1024
13-09-2017 16:20:32 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deployInternal main INFO  -     TaskManager memory = 2048
13-09-2017 16:20:32 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl.serviceInit main INFO  - Timeline service address: http://server:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
13-09-2017 16:20:33 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deployInternal main WARN  - The JobManager or TaskManager memory is below the smallest possible YARN Container size. The value of 'yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb' is '5120'. Please increase the memory size.YARN will allocate the smaller containers but the scheduler will account for the minimum-allocation-mb, maybe not all instances you requested will start.
13-09-2017 16:20:33 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.startAppMaster main WARN  - The configuration directory ('/flink-1.3.2/conf') contains both LOG4J and Logback configuration files. Please delete or rename one of them.
13-09-2017 16:20:33 org.apache.flink.yarn.Utils.setupLocalResource main INFO  - Copying from file:/flink-1.3.2/conf/log4j.properties to hdfs://nn:8020/user/user/.flink/application_1504618071460_3715/log4j.properties
13-09-2017 16:20:33 org.apache.flink.yarn.Utils.setupLocalResource main INFO  - Copying from file:/flink-1.3.2/lib to hdfs://nn:8020/user/user/.flink/application_1504618071460_3715/lib
13-09-2017 16:20:34 org.apache.flink.yarn.Utils.setupLocalResource main INFO  - Copying from file:/flink-1.3.2/conf/logback.xml to hdfs://nn:8020/user/user/.flink/application_1504618071460_3715/logback.xml
13-09-2017 16:20:34 org.apache.flink.yarn.Utils.setupLocalResource main INFO  - Copying from file:code/flink-test/target/flink-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to hdfs://nn:8020/user/user/.flink/application_1504618071460_3715/flink-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
13-09-2017 16:20:34 org.apache.flink.yarn.Utils.setupLocalResource main INFO  - Copying from file:/flink-1.3.2/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.3.2.jar to hdfs://nn:8020/user/user/.flink/application_1504618071460_3715/flink-dist_2.11-1.3.2.jar
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.flink.yarn.Utils.setupLocalResource main INFO  - Copying from /flink-1.3.2/conf/flink-conf.yaml to hdfs://nn:8020/user/user/.flink/application_1504618071460_3715/flink-conf.yaml
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.startAppMaster main INFO  - Adding delegation token to the AM container..
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getDelegationToken main INFO  - Created HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 126644 for user on ha-hdfs:nn
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal main INFO  - Got dt for hdfs://nn:8020; Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: ha-hdfs:nn, Ident: (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 126644 for user)
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.flink.yarn.Utils.obtainTokenForHBase main INFO  - Attempting to obtain Kerberos security token for HBase
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.flink.yarn.Utils.obtainTokenForHBase main INFO  - HBase is not available (not packaged with this application): ClassNotFoundException : "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration".
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.startAppMaster main INFO  - Submitting application master application_1504618071460_3715
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.submitApplication main INFO  - Submitted application application_1504618071460_3715
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.startAppMaster main INFO  - Waiting for the cluster to be allocated
13-09-2017 16:20:35 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.startAppMaster main INFO  - Deploying cluster, current state ACCEPTED
13-09-2017 16:20:40 org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.startAppMaster main INFO  - YARN application has been deployed successfully.
Cluster started: Yarn cluster with application id application_1504618071460_3715
Using address server2.corp.int:42683 to connect to JobManager.
JobManager web interface address http://server.corp.int:8088/proxy/application_1504618071460_3715/
Using the parallelism provided by the remote cluster (96). To use another parallelism, set it at the ./bin/flink client.
Starting execution of program
13-09-2017 16:20:40 org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run main INFO  - Starting program in interactive mode
13-09-2017 16:20:40 org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.logAndSysout main INFO  - Waiting until all TaskManagers have connected
Waiting until all TaskManagers have connected
13-09-2017 16:20:40 org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient$LazyActorSystemLoader.get main INFO  - Starting client actor system.

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:545)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:419)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:381)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:838)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:259)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1086)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1133)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1130)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1130)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get ClusterClient status from Application Client
        at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.getClusterStatus(YarnClusterClient.java:243)
        at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.waitForClusterToBeReady(YarnClusterClient.java:507)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:454)
        at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.submitJob(YarnClusterClient.java:205)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:442)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:429)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:926)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:410)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1605)
        at org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet.print(DataSet.scala:1726)
        at com.ing.diba.iaa.flink.FlinkWordCountTest$.main(FlinkWordCountTest.scala:21)
        at com.ing.diba.iaa.flink.FlinkWordCountTest.main(FlinkWordCountTest.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not connect to the leading JobManager. Please check that the JobManager is running.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.getJobManagerGateway(ClusterClient.java:789)
        at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.getClusterStatus(YarnClusterClient.java:238)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.LeaderRetrievalException: Could not retrieve the leader gateway.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils.retrieveLeaderGateway(LeaderRetrievalUtils.java:79)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.getJobManagerGateway(ClusterClient.java:784)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
        at scala.concurrent.Await.result(package.scala)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils.retrieveLeaderGateway(LeaderRetrievalUtils.java:77)
        ... 32 more
13-09-2017 16:20:51 org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.shutdownCluster main INFO  - Sending shutdown request to the Application Master
13-09-2017 16:20:51 org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient$LazApplicationClientLoader.get main INFO  - Start application client.
13-09-2017 16:20:51 org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.getApplicationStatus main WARN  - YARN reported application state FAILED
13-09-2017 16:20:51 org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.getApplicationStatus main WARN  - Diagnostics: Application application_1504618071460_3715 failed 1 times (global limit =2; local limit is =1) due to AM Container for appattempt_1504618071460_3715_000001 exited with  exitCode: 243
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://server.corp.int:8088/cluster/app/application_1504618071460_3715 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e18_1504618071460_3715_01_000001
Exit code: 243
Stack trace: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.runtime.ContainerExecutionException: Launch container failed
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.runtime.DefaultLinuxContainerRuntime.launchContainer(DefaultLinuxContainerRuntime.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.runtime.DelegatingLinuxContainerRuntime.launchContainer(DelegatingLinuxContainerRuntime.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Shell output: main : command provided 1
main : run as user is user
main : requested yarn user is user
Getting exit code file...
Creating script paths...
Writing pid file...
Writing to tmp file /BIGDATA/hadoop/yarn/local/nmPrivate/application_1504618071460_3715/container_e18_1504618071460_3715_01_000001/container_e18_1504618071460_3715_01_000001.pid.tmp
Writing to cgroup task files...
Creating local dirs...
Launching container...
Getting exit code file...
Creating script paths...


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 243
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
13-09-2017 16:20:51 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Notification about new leader address akka.tcp://flink@server2.corp.int:42683/user/jobmanager with session ID 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
13-09-2017 16:20:51 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:20:51 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Received address of new leader akka.tcp://flink@server2.corp.int:42683/user/jobmanager with session ID 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
13-09-2017 16:20:51 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Disconnect from JobManager null.
13-09-2017 16:20:51 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@server2.corp.int:42683/user/jobmanager.
13-09-2017 16:20:52 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@server2.corp.int:42683/user/jobmanager.
13-09-2017 16:20:52 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:20:53 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@server2.corp.int:42683/user/jobmanager.
13-09-2017 16:20:53 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:20:54 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:20:55 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 INFO  - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@server2.corp.int:42683/user/jobmanager.
13-09-2017 16:20:55 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:20:56 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:20:57 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:20:58 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:20:59 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 INFO  - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@server2.corp.int:42683/user/jobmanager.
13-09-2017 16:20:59 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:21:00 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:21:01 org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.shutdownCluster main WARN  - Error while stopping YARN cluster.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:169)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:169)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.ready(package.scala:169)
        at scala.concurrent.Await.ready(package.scala)
        at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.shutdownCluster(YarnClusterClient.java:367)
        at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.finalizeCluster(YarnClusterClient.java:337)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.shutdown(ClusterClient.java:245)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:267)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1086)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1133)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1130)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1130)
13-09-2017 16:21:01 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 INFO  - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
13-09-2017 16:21:02 org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.shutdownCluster main INFO  - Application application_1504618071460_3715 finished with state FAILED and final state FAILED at 1505312441186
13-09-2017 16:21:02 org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.shutdownCluster main WARN  - Application failed. Diagnostics Application application_1504618071460_3715 failed 1 times (global limit =2; local limit is =1) due to AM Container for appattempt_1504618071460_3715_000001 exited with  exitCode: 243
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://server.corp.int:8088/cluster/app/application_1504618071460_3715 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e18_1504618071460_3715_01_000001
Exit code: 243
Stack trace: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.runtime.ContainerExecutionException: Launch container failed
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.runtime.DefaultLinuxContainerRuntime.launchContainer(DefaultLinuxContainerRuntime.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.runtime.DelegatingLinuxContainerRuntime.launchContainer(DelegatingLinuxContainerRuntime.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Shell output: main : command provided 1
main : run as user is user
main : requested yarn user is user
Getting exit code file...
Creating script paths...
Writing pid file...
Writing to tmp file /BIGDATA/hadoop/yarn/local/nmPrivate/application_1504618071460_3715/container_e18_1504618071460_3715_01_000001/container_e18_1504618071460_3715_01_000001.pid.tmp
Writing to cgroup task files...
Creating local dirs...
Launching container...
Getting exit code file...
Creating script paths...


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 243
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
13-09-2017 16:21:02 org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.shutdownCluster main WARN  - If log aggregation is activated in the Hadoop cluster, we recommend to retrieve the full application log using this command:
        yarn logs -applicationId application_1504618071460_3715
(It sometimes takes a few seconds until the logs are aggregated)
13-09-2017 16:21:02 org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient.shutdownCluster main INFO  - YARN Client is shutting down
13-09-2017 16:21:02 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Stopped Application client.
13-09-2017 16:21:02 grizzled.slf4j.Logger.info flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 INFO  - Disconnect from JobManager null.
```

Comment: I'm also facing a similar issue. Were you able to figure out a solution?